# How to get NavigationPage.TitleView to work in MAUI?

Tags: maui

This seems like it should be so simple but I am unable to make any changes to the appearnce of the top bar of a NavigationPage.

Here is the very simple ContentPage that gets launched as a NavigationPage.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="FasterWaxer.NavPage"
             xmlns:mct="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit">

    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <Label Text="This is a test"/>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>

</ContentPage>
```

Here is the trivial code behind...

```
public partial class NavPage: ContentPage
{
    public NavPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And here is the code that launches the page...

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new NavPage());
```

Do I somehow need to declare the offending page to be a NavigationPage object instead of ContentPage object? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage?view=net-maui-7.0#display-views-in-the-navigation-bar): “ Many views won't appear in the navigation bar unless the size of the view is specified with the WidthRequest and HeightRequest properties.”

Comment: I tried many variations of HeightRequest and WidthRequest with no luck.

Comment: Maui GitHub Repo have many issues related to TitleView. You could have hit by one of them. If your issue is not reported than you can report your issue there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to [Create the root page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage?view=net-maui-7.0#create-the-root-page),just as follows.

Please refer to the following code:

```
public partial class App : Application 
{
      public App()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

        //MainPage = new AppShell();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());

    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage 
{

      public MainPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void OnBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         Navigation.PushAsync(new NavPage());
    }
}
```

**NavPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.NavPage"
             Title="NavPage">
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <Label Text="This is a test"  TextColor="White"/>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: hmm...I'm a little hesitant to try changing this fundamental approach to starting a shell app. I'm not sure of the downstream implications. In my case, the NavigationPage for which I'm trying to customize the title is 3 levels away from the main page in the page navigation stack.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a simple but unintuitive answer. If you're using a Shell app, use <Shell.TitleView> instead of <NavigationPage.TitleView>. I expect that @Jessie answer would work too but this feels a little less intrusive.